# Wildcard with cmd files

Tags: for-loop, cmd, delete-file

I am currently using this statement:

```
for /d %%X in (C:\Users\*) do (del %%X\Desktop\deleteme.txt )
```

Although I would like to use the "%%X" in to parts of this statement

e.g.

```
del %%X\%%X\deleteme.txt
```

How can this be done?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to recursively delete files. This could be done by using the del command directly. By typing:

del deleteme.txt /s

deleteme.txt will be deleted from all subfolders. If that is not what you want you also could have your for loop call another batch file to perform the deletion from sub folders.

%%X will not work, as it gets fully expanded first.